# Unable to set environment variable inside docker container when calling sh file from Dockerfile CMD

Tags: docker, apache-spark, docker-compose, environment-variables, sh

I am following [this](https://github.com/mvillarrealb/docker-spark-cluster) link to create a spark cluster. I am able to run the spark cluster. However, I have to give an absolute path to start `spark-shell`. I am trying to set environment variables i.e. `PATH` and a few others in `start-shell.sh`. However, it's not setting that inside container. I tried printing it using `printenv` inside the container. But these variables are never reflected.

Am I trying to set environment variables incorrectly? Spark cluster is running successfully though.

I am using docker-compose.yml to build and recreate an image and container.

> docker-compose up --build

##### Dockerfile

```
# builder step used to download and configure spark environment
FROM openjdk:11.0.11-jre-slim-buster as builder

# Add Dependencies for PySpark
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl vim wget software-properties-common ssh net-tools ca-certificates python3 python3-pip python3-numpy python3-matplotlib python3-scipy python3-pandas python3-simpy

# JDBC driver download and install
ADD https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2168494 /usr/share/java

RUN update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/python" "python" "$(which python3)" 1

# Fix the value of PYTHONHASHSEED
# Note: this is needed when you use Python 3.3 or greater
ENV SPARK_VERSION=3.1.2 \
HADOOP_VERSION=3.2 \
SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark \
PYTHONHASHSEED=1

# Download and uncompress spark from the apache archive
RUN wget --no-verbose -O apache-spark.tgz "https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz" \
&& mkdir -p ${SPARK_HOME} \
&& tar -xf apache-spark.tgz -C ${SPARK_HOME} --strip-components=1 \
&& rm apache-spark.tgz
```

##### My Dockerfile-spark

When using `SPARK_BIN="${SPARK_HOME}/bin/` under ENV in Dockerfile, environment variable get's set. It is visible inside the docker container by using `printenv`

```
FROM apache-spark

WORKDIR ${SPARK_HOME}

ENV SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077 \
SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080 \
SPARK_LOG_DIR=${SPARK_HOME}/logs \
SPARK_MASTER_LOG=${SPARK_HOME}/logs/spark-master.out \
SPARK_WORKER_LOG=${SPARK_HOME}/logs/spark-worker.out \
SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT=8080 \
SPARK_MASTER="spark://spark-master:7077" \
SPARK_WORKLOAD="master"        

COPY start-spark.sh /

CMD ["/bin/bash", "/start-spark.sh"]
```

##### start-spark.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
. "$SPARK_HOME/bin/load-spark-env.sh"

export SPARK_BIN="${SPARK_HOME}/bin/" # This doesn't work here
export PATH="${SPARK_HOME}/bin/:${PATH}" # This doesn't work here      

# When the spark work_load is master run class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
if [ "$SPARK_WORKLOAD" == "master" ];
then

export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=`hostname`           # This works here

cd $SPARK_BIN && ./spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip $SPARK_MASTER_HOST --port $SPARK_MASTER_PORT --webui-port $SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT >> $SPARK_MASTER_LOG.
```

My File structure is

- dockerfile
- dockerfile-spark # this uses pre-built image created by dockerfile
- start-spark.sh # invoked buy dockerfile-spark
- docker-compose.yml # uses build parameter to build an image from dockerfile-spark

From inside the master container

```
root@3abbd4508121:/opt/spark# export
declare -x HADOOP_VERSION="3.2"
declare -x HOME="/root"
declare -x HOSTNAME="3abbd4508121"
declare -x JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/openjdk-11"
declare -x JAVA_VERSION="11.0.11+9"
declare -x LANG="C.UTF-8"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
declare -x PWD="/opt/spark"
declare -x PYTHONHASHSEED="1"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SPARK_HOME="/opt/spark"
declare -x SPARK_LOCAL_IP="spark-master"
declare -x SPARK_LOG_DIR="/opt/spark/logs"
declare -x SPARK_MASTER="spark://spark-master:7077"
declare -x SPARK_MASTER_LOG="/opt/spark/logs/spark-master.out"
declare -x SPARK_MASTER_PORT="7077"
declare -x SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT="8080"
declare -x SPARK_VERSION="3.1.2"
declare -x SPARK_WORKER_LOG="/opt/spark/logs/spark-worker.out"
declare -x SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT="8080"
declare -x SPARK_WORKLOAD="master"
declare -x TERM="xterm"
root@3abbd4508121:/opt/spark#
```

Comment: What leads you to think the environment variables aren't getting set?  Nothing that you show actually includes a `printenv` call.

Comment: @DavidMaze When using `SPARK_BIN="${SPARK_HOME}/bin/" and `PATH="${SPARK_HOME}/bin/:${PATH}"` in DockerFile, it works however when using these in `start-spark.sh`. It doesn't work Someone told me to use `. /start-spark.sh` due to shell global vs local context. However it's throwing different error.

Comment: The couple of places you say "inside the container", how do you get there?  (A `docker exec` debugging shell won't see environment variables you set in an entrypoint wrapper script.)

Comment: I used `docker exec -it sparkdocs_spark-master_1 /bin/bash` to get into the container shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to set environment variables in Docker, and a couple of different ways to run processes.  A container normally runs one process, which is controlled by the image's `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` settings.  If you `docker exec` a second process in the container, that does not run as a child process of the main process, and will not see environment variables that are set by that main process.

In the setup you show here, the `start-spark.sh` script is the main container process (it is the image's `CMD`).  If you `docker exec your-container printenv`, it will see things set in the `Dockerfile` but not things set in this script.

Things like filesystem paths will generally be fixed every time you run the container, no matter what command you're running there, so you can specify these in the Dockerfile

```sh
ENV SPARK_BIN=${SPARK_HOME}/bin PATH=${SPARK_BIN}:${PATH}
```

You can specify both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD` in your Dockerfile; if you do, the `CMD` is passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`.  This leads to a useful pattern where the `CMD` is a standard shell command, and the `ENTRYPOINT` is a wrapper that does first-time setup and then runs it.  You can split your script into two:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# spark-env.sh
. "${SPARK_BIN}/load-spark-env.snh"
exec "$@"
```

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# start-spark.sh
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master \
  --ip "$SPARK_MASTER_HOST" \
  --port "$SPARK_MASTER_PORT" \
  --webui-port "$SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT"
```

Then in your Dockerfile specify both parts

```sh
COPY spark-env.sh start-spark.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/spark-env.sh"] # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["/start-spark.sh"] # or any other valid CMD
```

This is useful for your debugging since it's straightforward to override the `CMD` in a `docker run` or `docker-compose run` instruction, leaving the `ENTRYPOINT` in place.

```sh
docker-compose run spark \
  printenv
```

This launches a new container based on all of the same Dockerfile setup.  When it runs, it runs `printenv` instead of the `CMD` in the image.  This will do the first-time setup in the `ENTRYPOINT` script, and then the final `exec "$@"` line will run `printenv` instead of starting the Spark application.  This will show you the environment the application will have when it starts.

Comment: Quite elaborated answer. +1. I would like to know if it is still possible to set an environment variable from start-spark.sh that is also visible from other sessions without specifying env in dockerfile. Just wondering if it's even possible. I understand it would be a bad design though.

Comment: If you set an environment variable in one process, it's never visible in another, with the one specific exception that a child process inherits its parent's environment when fork(2) is called (but after that point the two processes' environments are separate).  That applies to `docker exec` too; the extra debugging shell or other process is not a child of the main container process and can't see its environment.  (Use `docker exec` sparingly, as a debugging tool, not as a way to get a "session".)